# How can I access 'unassigned_unmapped' reads in a BAM file output using Rsubread?

Tags: r

How to access 'unassigned_unmapped' reads from .BAM file output.

I aligned to a refrence using the align function in Rsubread, and know that the BAM files store the unused reads but cannot find commands to access these reads and export them as FASTA/FASTQ in the user manual...anyone know how to access them?